# Button OnClick event not firing with one textbox in the form

Tags: asp.net

I came across a very strange occurrence with ASP.NET onclick event in IE (other browsers doesn't seem to have this problem). When there is only one textbox field in a form, the onclick event doesn't fire when you enter text and hit Enter/Return. The event does fire when you click on the actual submit button. When there are two or more fields in the form, hitting Enter/Return works just fine.

It's very strange. Thought it was something with my IE, but checked other machines, and every one of them had the same problem.

I had setup this really simple page as a test:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(((Button)sender).Text);
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When one of the textbox is removed, the `btnSubmit_Click` event doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: which framework version?

Comment: I just confirmed the behavior in vs2008 with IE8. No error. The postback occurs, however it appears that the page simply reloads.  Further, the IsPostBack variable is set to true although the event handler doesn't execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `defaultButton` property of `Panel` or `Form` is used to ensure Enter Key Submission. Typically people used to Enter Key submission and if it is disabled, it might be annoying certain times.

The `defaultButton` really provides a way to handle Enter Keys for respective portions of the page when the focus is there.

Comment: Setting the defaultButton corrects the issue.  Although why it works when multiple textbox controls exist on the page but not when only one exists is beyond me.

Comment: thank you! You saved my day! I've never used the defaultButton property before - new thing I learned today! Looks like adding the `defaultButton` property adds JS that performs a click event on the button for the form the field had focus on. @Chris, yeah, it's very strange that with multiple textboxes the enter key works without needing to set the `defaultButton` property. And it's also strange that this behavior is only in IE.

Comment: had exact same issue and `defaultButton` solves the issue perfectly. Means i have to unecessarily send an extra div element to the client, but i think it's a fair trade off. Cheers!